# Can't create svg line, but creating svg circle works fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I'm trying to create a cicle and a line in my svg. But for some reason I can't seem to create/add the line to my svg.

This is my code:

```
findTop = wrapper.find("g[data-node-id='1']");
var obj = findTop.parent();
var newobj = obj.clone();

$(obj).append(document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle"))

$(obj)
  .parent()
  .find("circle")
  .unwrap()
  .attr("class", "get-btn trigger-btn")
  .attr("data-btn-id", "1")
  .attr("cx", "257.5")
  .attr("cy", "100")
  .attr("r", "20");

$(obj).append(document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line'))
  .attr({
    id: "line2",
    x1: 0,
    y1: 0,
    x2: 300,
    y2: 300
  });
```

Do anyone have an idea why I cant add the line to my svg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line actually exists. You need to add a stroke to it:

```
$(obj).append(document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'line')).attr({
    id: "line2",
    x1: 0,
    y1: 0,
    x2: 300,
    y2: 300,
    stroke: "red",
    "stroke-width": 2
});
```